# Eliminate the gap between navigation and title in Beamer Presentation

Tags: latex, beamer

I am trying to eliminate the line gap between the navigation and title. Any ideas how I can remove it? I am using the `\useoutertheme{miniframes}` theme.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `miniframes` outer theme normally includes another coloured bar for subsections (which is not visible with your colour choices).

[image]

You can switch it off with the `subsection=false` option:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{whale}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{title}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Laurence_jj You're welcome!